# IBM Informix How to pass string value in parameter

Tags: sql, informix

Could anybody help me with creating the correct SQL query for Informix db?
I have the function in which I'm trying to prepare an SQL query from a string as described in the Informix docs

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunction( stringval VARCHAR( 32 )) RETURNING INT;
DEFINE c_query varchar(250);
LET c_query = 'select first 1 someid, somevalue from sometable where sname= '||stringval||' order by somevalue;
PREPARE c_stmt
FROM c_query;

DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;
OPEN c_cur ;
FETCH c_cur INTO sp_id ;
CLOSE c_cur;
FREE c_cur;
FREE c_stmt;
RETURN sp_id;
END FUNCION;
```

And when I try to test it, I invoke it as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table(functionname('fo'))
```

But unfortunately I get error message with text:

```
Column (fo) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in this case i get the same error message as without quotes

Comment: when i try to hardcode string instead parameter i get the same error

Comment: 'select first 1 someid from sometable where sname= '||'stringval'; returns the same error message

Comment: i can`t because the query prepares from the string, as shown in the code  above and it text enclosed in quotes

Comment: simple query works fine, but i can`t to use it in the function because the informix limitation disallow to use order by clause anywhere except foreach

Comment: it`s just example of code, i already fixed  it

Comment: You need to get the `fo` wrapped in quotes in the query.  `LET c_query = 'SELECT FIRST 1 someid FROM sometable WHERE sname = ''' || stringval || ''''` — count the quotes carefully (and make sure you know what each one is doing).  And that assumes there is no single quote inside `stringval`; if there are any, they need to be doubled up too.  This is why trying to do it by hand is vulnerable to SQL Injection — use placeholders instead.

Comment: The fact is as i found in docs of informix it disallowed to use input parameters in sql string and recommends to use placeholders instead. But i still can`t use following clauses:  like %somestring%. I get error message about illegal characters.

Comment: If you want to create a LIKE clause like that, then you'd need to wrap what is passed with two `%` symbols and then pass the wrapped string for the placeholder: `DEFINE like_str VARCHAR(34); LET like_str = '%' || somestring || '%';` and then `OPEN c_cur USING like_str;`.  You can add other parameters as you need to.

Comment: Also, it isn't disallowed — the system cannot prevent you from doing it.  However, it is not recommended, and I demonstrated some of how to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i`ll try it

Comment: With input parameter all works fine, but i still don`t understand how can i use LIKE clause when i need to compare input parameter with part of the field value?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "use LIKE clause when I need part of the field value, not input parameter".  Please reword that requirement, and maybe show an exampe.

Comment: For example let dsql = 'select * from sometable s where ? like %s.name%';

Comment: You can't treat column names like data values.  If you want to supply a column name, then you have to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the number corresponding to a name of `fo`, you'd have to enclose it in quotes, which in turn means you'd need to escape the quotes in the string.  You need to read about [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.org/327) because what you're proposing is very vulnerable to SQL Injection.

If the object of the exercise is to get the query shown executed, then you should use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunction(stringval VARCHAR(32)) RETURNING INT;

    DEFINE sp_id INTEGER;

    SELECT FIRST 1 someid
      INTO sp_id
      FROM sometable
     WHERE sname= stringval
     ORDER BY somevalue;

    RETURN sp_id;

END FUNCTION
```

If the object of the exercise is to use dynamic SQL, then you should consider using placeholders, like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunction(stringval VARCHAR(32)) RETURNING INT;

    DEFINE sp_id INTEGER;
    DEFINE c_query varchar(250);
    LET c_query = 'SELECT FIRST 1 someid FROM sometable WHERE sname = ? ORDER BY somevalue';
    PREPARE c_stmt FROM c_query;

    DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;
    OPEN c_cur USING stringval;
    FETCH c_cur INTO sp_id;
    CLOSE c_cur;
    FREE c_cur;
    FREE c_stmt;
    RETURN sp_id;

END FUNCTION
```

Untested on your table.  The code I tested was:

```
CREATE FUNCTION atomic_number(symbol VARCHAR(3)) RETURNING INTEGER;
    DEFINE num INTEGER;
    SELECT atomic_number INTO num FROM elements AS e WHERE e.symbol = symbol;
    RETURN num;
END FUNCTION
```

and:

```
CREATE FUNCTION atomic_number(symbol VARCHAR(3)) RETURNING INTEGER;
    DEFINE num INTEGER;
    DEFINE c_query varchar(250);
    LET c_query = 'SELECT FIRST 1 atomic_number FROM elements WHERE symbol = ? ORDER BY atomic_number';
    PREPARE c_stmt FROM c_query;

    DECLARE c_cur CURSOR FOR c_stmt;
    OPEN c_cur USING symbol;
    FETCH c_cur INTO num;
    CLOSE c_cur;
    FREE c_cur;
    FREE c_stmt;
    RETURN num;
END FUNCTION
```

These run against a 'table of elements' (as in 'Periodic Table'), with structure:

```
CREATE TABLE elements
(
    atomic_number   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                    CHECK (atomic_number > 0 AND atomic_number < 120),
    symbol          CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name            CHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    atomic_weight   DECIMAL(8, 4) NOT NULL,
    pt_period       SMALLINT NOT NULL
                    CHECK (pt_period BETWEEN 1 AND 7),
    pt_group        CHAR(2) NOT NULL
                    -- 'L' for Lanthanoids, 'A' for Actinoids
                    CHECK (pt_group IN ('1', '2', 'L', 'A', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                                        '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                                        '14', '15', '16', '17', '18')),
    stable          CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL
                    CHECK (stable IN ('Y', 'N'))
);

INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  1, 'H',   'Hydrogen',        1.0079, 1, '1',  'Y');
…
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(118, 'Og',  'Oganesson',     294.2100, 7, '18', 'N');
```

Comment: when I try to use a `SELECT` with an `ORDER BY` to assign values with `LET`or `INTO` i get a `-201    A syntax error has occurred`, so it seems it cannot be done directly (as the OP mentioned). However I can use a table expression to wrap the `ORDER BY` as a workaround (no idea of what implications it has on performance).

Comment: @LuísMarques: writing SPL is an unpleasant game of 'chase the syntax error' at the best of times.  I can't say why you're getting problems.  I tested with Informix 12.10.FC6 on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.  Now, I didn't test the singleton SELECT  with an ORDER BY clause, but I did test the dynamic SQL with it.  It worked OK for me.  What system did you test on?  What's the exact syntax?  (Consider using email: see my profile.)

Comment: @LuísMarques: there was a missing quote in the second stored procedure.  I've updated the answer to fix that.

Comment: The only way to use order by clause in function context is dynamic sql.

Comment: Why do you want to use `SELECT` rather than `EXECUTE FUNCTION somefunction('fo')`?  It's an annoying inconsistency if dynamic SQL allows you to use ORDER BY and static SQL does not.  Either both should allow or both should disallow it.  However, annoying inconsistencies do occur.  You may use dynamic SQL if you wish.  There's nothing to stop you using the same parameter many times in the USING clause, thereby 'assigning' one of the input parameters to several placeholders.  Two is just a rather limited case of 'many'.

Comment: Note that it would have been easier to answer had you provided a sample table schema (it need only have two or three columns in it) and some sample data (it need only be five rows).  And then you'd need to specify the expected output for various operations.  You should also show your actual output — but the code you show doesn't even compile (no define for `sp_id`; misspelling FUNCION for FUNCTION; possibly others).

Comment: As far as I know, Informix also allows you to use the order by clause in the foreach body in spl, but in my case it's unnecessary.

Comment: Is only reason to create this function is that in spl of informix we can`t use the select statement in the foreach body, but we can use the result of the function which returns select statement result instead

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you'd be doing if there wasn't a restriction in Informix.  You can use a SELECT statement to control a FOREACH in SPL, and you can return multiple rows using WITH RESUME.  But I'm not sure whether that's something you missed or there's some other problem.  Maybe you should show the SPL/SQL code you'd like to execute; there may be a way to do what you want more directly.  Also show how you'd want to invoke it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. Everything works perfectly.